# Update(GameTime gameTime) - how to do task some specific times per second?

Tags: c#, time, xna

I'm using C# and XNA. And there's this method in Game class

```
    Update(GameTime gameTime)
```

I need to execute my function inside this method about 4 times per second. How can I acheive that?

So far I could only know when new second starts by doing

```
    if (gameTime.TotalGameTime.Milliseconds == 0)
```

But I need a way to run my function some specific times per second. But I can't figure out how I can do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a separate counter, and the interval at which to call your function. For 4 times a second, this is `float interval = 1/4;`.

Every frame, update the counter by the number of milliseconds that have passed since the last frame.

Check if this counter is greater than interval; if so, at least `interval` seconds have passed and the function needs to be called.

Answer (score 1):

Another option may be using the *Timer* class from *System.Timers*

This class allows running recurring events in your application/game.

For more information, read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx